# error in EXECUTE sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server

when i execute this query, i get error of 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VIEW''
please help me, what is the problem in this query?

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql 
N'
CREATE VIEW LastDayOfMonth
AS
SELECT @MAX = MAX(DATEPART(DAY,CurrencyRateDate))AS CurrencyRateDate FROM Sales.CurrencyRate 
WHERE 
DATEPART(YEAR,CurrencyRateDate)=@YEAR
AND
DATEPART(MONTH,CurrencyRateDate)= @MONTH',
N' @YEAR CHAR(4),@MONTH CHAR(2)',
@YEAR = '2004',
@MONTH = '02';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no obvious reason to do what you're doing here either using a view or using `sp_executesql`.

The following should work:

```
DECLARE @MAX INT
DECLARE @YEAR INT
DECLARE @MONTH INT

SET @YEAR = 2004
SET @MONTH = 02

SELECT @MAX = MAX(DATEPART(DAY,CurrencyRateDate))AS CurrencyRateDate FROM Sales.CurrencyRate 
WHERE 
DATEPART(YEAR,CurrencyRateDate)=@YEAR
AND
DATEPART(MONTH,CurrencyRateDate)= @MONTH
```

and to show the result:

```
SELECT @MAX
```

If this isn't what you're trying to do, perhaps you could edit the question and clarify?

Comment: Well, I can imagine one reason to do this in a stored procedure, called Reporting Services ;-). However, that doesn't explain the use of a view..

Comment: @vstrien - I see what you mean - but why would you create a view in an SSRS query - particularly one as simple as this?

Comment: I agree with you on that. Of course it's of no use to create views from within a SSRS report :).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the use of the variable @MAX, which isn't declared. When you want to return this value, you won't need a variable, just do it like this:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql 
N'
CREATE VIEW LastDayOfMonth
AS
SELECT 
   MAX(DATEPART(DAY,CurrencyRateDate))AS CurrencyRateDate AS Maximum
FROM Sales.CurrencyRate 
WHERE 
DATEPART(YEAR,CurrencyRateDate)=@YEAR
AND
DATEPART(MONTH,CurrencyRateDate)= @MONTH',
N' @YEAR CHAR(4),@MONTH CHAR(2)',
@YEAR = '2004',
@MONTH = '02';
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?:

```
EXECUTE DATABASENAME..sp_executesql 
N'
CREATE VIEW LastDayOfMonth
AS
SELECT @MAX = MAX(DATEPART(DAY,CurrencyRateDate))AS CurrencyRateDate FROM Sales.CurrencyRate 
WHERE 
DATEPART(YEAR,CurrencyRateDate)=@YEAR
AND
DATEPART(MONTH,CurrencyRateDate)= @MONTH',
N' @YEAR CHAR(4),@MONTH CHAR(2)',
@YEAR = '2004',
@MONTH = '02';
```

If you still get problems, then it's probably going to be because you can't work `parameters` with `views` ..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. It seems that you cannot use parameters with view. Instead process the SQL to include the parameters:

```
set @sql = N'create view as select * from table where year = ' + cast(@year as varchar(4));
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```