# Is it possible to use sp_executesql to create a view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-express

I can use the following statements to create an empty stored proc in my database:

```
declare @statement as NVARCHAR(250) 
set @statement  = N'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[vwAS2ConnectionUpdated] as' 
exec dbo.sp_executesql @statement
```

However, if I attempt to create a view using the same statements (except for using VIEW in the create statement)* I get an error.

```
declare @statement as NVARCHAR(250) 
set @statement  = N'CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwAS2ConnectionUpdated] as' 
exec dbo.sp_executesql @statement
```

The error is :

```
Incorrect syntax near 'as'.
```

Can you tell me why that might be occurring?
Is it possible to create a view using sp_executesql?

**Note**: I've already browsed other similar SO Q&A but their is no definitive answer.
Here is one example I've read through:
[error in EXECUTE sp_executesql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277302/error-in-execute-sp-executesql)

**Note 2**: I am running this on a SQL Server Express instance -- SQL Server 2014 SP3 CU3 - 12.0.6259.0 (latest build)

**Additional Info**

When you use the code to create the SP it ends up creating an SP that looks like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[vwAS2ConnectionUpdated] as
```

However, it will not create a View like that.  Maybe this is a bug in SQL Server parser, etc. or that sp_executesql (that it allows the SP to be created like that??)

Comment: Where is the rest of your statement? a `VIEW` is a precompiled `SELECT` statement; your `VIEW` definition has no `SELECT` statement

Comment: _Is it possible to use sp_executesql to create a view?_ Yes, but why you want to do so?

Comment: @Larnu This is part of a larger script which is implemented by RoundhousE which checks for the existence of the SP (or in this case View).  This was just a snippet of that script.

Comment: @Sami It's a part of a larger script which determines if the VIEW exists and if not it creates it then runs ALTER afterwards. It's a pattern / process for using RoundhousE.

Comment: No one can debug code that cannot be seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use `CREATE VIEW` via `sp_executesql`, see the following example:

```
declare @statement as NVARCHAR(250) 
set @statement  = N'CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MyView] as SELECT 1 [ColumnName]' 
exec dbo.sp_executesql @statement

SELECT  [ColumnName]
FROM    [dbo].[MyView]
```

The reason you're seeing an error is that you're not specifying the `SELECT` statement that the view should execute. If you look at the documentation for [`CREATE VIEW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), you'll see that `select_statement` isn't listed in [brackets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (`[]`), which means that it's not optional.

The documentation for [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) shows the syntax for the body of the procedure to be:

```
AS { [ BEGIN ] sql_statement [;] [ ...n ] [ END ] }
```

This breaks down to:

- It starts with `AS`
- The `BEGIN` and `END` are optional
- There can be one or more `sql_statement`s optionally terminated with a semi-colon

I can't find the syntax for `sql_statement` anywhere after a cursory search, but it certainly looks like an empty string is a valid `sql_statement`. This is supported by the fact that `CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AnotherProcedure] as ;` will create a stored procedure.

Comment: This is the best answer so far, but I guess the related question is, "Why can you create an SP like that, but not a VIew like that?  That's the root of my question.

Comment: I'm going to mark this one as the answer because you mentioned the Create View docs and the brackets which show AS statement as not optional.  I compared that to the Create PROCEDURE and it shows that part as optional.  IT's odd, but at least now I have a definitive answer.

Comment: @raddevus, I've added a bit more detail, picking out the bit of the syntax from the `CREATE PROCEDURE` documentation =)

Comment: Note: It will throw an error if the `VIEW` is already exists.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to use sp_executesql to create a view?

Yes, it's possible to create a view like

```
EXEC sp_exeutesql N'DROP VIEW IF EXISTS [dbo].[MyView]; CREATE VIEW [MyView] AS SELECT 1 AS Col';
```

Now, let's go to the *Why not just `N'CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwAS2ConnectionUpdated] as'`*

By visiting the **[`CREATE VIEW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** page, you can see the definition:

> Creates a virtual **table** whose contents (columns and rows)...

While `N'CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwAS2ConnectionUpdated] as'` doesn't seems to has columns and rows, cause when you define a table the table should have columns.

Also, if you take a look at the syntax you'll find

> AS select_statement

So, it's a part of the syntax of `CREATE VIEW`, which mean you need a `SELECT` statement.

Also, if you take a look at the **Arguments** part, you will see

> *select_statement*
>
> **Is the SELECT statement that defines the view.** The statement can use more than one table and other views. Appropriate permissions are required to select from the objects referenced in the SELECT clause of the view that is created.

So, if you don't include a `SELECT` statement, you don't define your view at all, it's the definition of the `VIEW`, thus it should be used.

Comment: Very good info, really appreciate it, but other post was first so I'll mark as answer.  Thanks for providing valuable details though.

Comment: @raddevus It's ok, just pick the best one, so readers can learn from the posts and know which is the best ;)